# Security alert when using "longpoling" connection with SignalR, while in secure connection (HTTPS) | IE8

Tags: asp.net, https, internet-explorer-8, signalr, long-polling

There is only one problem, I am just getting a `"Securty Waring"` alert in `IE 8` in my SignalR chat application while in HTTPS

[image]

I am using `longpolling` as transport type when in `IE8`. Its working fine in all other IE browers.

```
self.Connect = function () {
     hubConn.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function (result) {
                ///--
     }).fail(function (error) {
                ///--
         alert("error" + error);
     });
}
```

When I tried fiddler, the security warning appeared with a signalr ajax call as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Please add those details from forum.asp.net including the extra screenshots here so that the question here is complete.

Comment: See the answer here on How to avoid security warning in IE when landing an HTTPS page? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2899212/1399964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various possibilities of security warning in IE is explained in the below url

[ie7-this-page-contains-both-secure-and-nonsecure-items](http://weblogs.asp.net/rchartier/archive/2008/03/12/ie7-this-page-contains-both-secure-and-nonsecure-items.aspx)

The problem was actually not with the signalr chat and i have detailed the cause of my issue in the url given below.

[Security+warning+in+IE+version+8](http://forums.asp.net/t/1891981.aspx/2/10?Security%20warning%20in%20IE%20version%208%20when%20used%20signalr%20in%20https%20context)

Thanks guys for your support :)

Best,

Linto Sebastian